# Spring boot + OAuth2, Throw server_error

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm getting internal server error while running my code. i have no idea what happened because It shows nothing in console.

here my AuthorizationServerConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Bean
    TokenStore jdbcTokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(jdbcTokenStore());
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

here my websecurityconfig code

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

this is my userserviceImpl

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailRepository userDetailRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Optional<User> optionalUser = userDetailRepository.findByUsername(name);

        optionalUser.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username or password wrong"));

        UserDetails userDetails = new AuthUserDetail(optionalUser.get());
        new AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker().check(userDetails);

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

this is how i get token

- http://localhost:8802/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=abc&scope=READ&password=abc *

**output**

{
"error": "server_error",
"error_description": "Internal Server Error"
}

Comment: ```Internal Server Error``` may be anything, it's better to debug project and check where throws this exception exactly .

Comment: You need to enable debug to be able to see some logs and figure out at what point you are facing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping to resolved error.